# How can I map json data dynamically so that my code won't break?

Tags: java, json

The problem is this: I am receiving a file from a vendor that is in JSON format. Currently, I have a POJO class that contains mappings for the JSON fields. Since it is a file and not an API, we are unsure when the fields may change in the future.

Sample JSON: { "CUSTOMERID": "123456", "firstName": "test1", "middleName": "", "lastName": "last2", "suffix": "Mr.", "fullName": " John", "companyName": "IT", "SSN": "" }

If in the future, they change 'CUSTOMERID' to 'MEMBERID,' then my code would fail. How can I overcome this?"

Comment: You can have your own mapping file. Either a properties file or a JSON file. That file can have mappings between the fields in the incoming file and the fields in your POJO. That mapping file would be outside your deployment, a kind of data file. It could be a file OR it could be env variables or AWS Parameter Store or something if you are using cloud. Only that data needs to be changed when incoming file's field names change. No deploment needed. No change in your code.

Comment: Forgot to mention. If something like this is not readily available, you can use Java Reflection APIs to dynamically call setters on your POJO.

Comment: Your JSON is a single level map to String.  Define your POJO with one element as type `Map<String, String>` can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do a conceptual misunderstanding:

> Since it is a file and not an API, we are unsure when the fields may change in the future.

You try to bypass the API concepts by using files directly. But you still not avoid the core problem:

> If in the future, they change 'CUSTOMERID' to 'MEMBERID,' then my code would fail.

The API concepts are made to overcome this issue. So a correct approach would be to abandon file transfert and generate a API definition with DTO based on your Json file  (use open API / swagger editor).

This is gonna be the `V1`, then when you change from `CUSTOMERID`' to '`MEMBERID`, it's gonna be a `V2`. You just need to write the implementation for both cases.